# Use Textbox or someother element to show data to user

Tags: jquery, html, jqxgrid

I am using textbox to display the data being fetched from database , but sometime the data is long text .So for the user prospective it's not looking nice . Is there any other options to textbox . Suggestions or solutions needed .

Code i am using

**HTML----**

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;<div><div style="width:12%;float:left; margin-left:2%;" >Material</div> <div style="margin-left:15%;" id="serialno1" >Please Select </div></div><br />
```

**Script----**

```
$("#serialno1").html("<div style='margin: 10px; background-color:#CDD9E1;'>" + event.args.element.id + "</div>");
```

Right now i am not fetching data from db , will it possible to get data and display as what i am using now..

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `<div>` and apply some style to that to allow scrolling - it's an easier way to display read-only data and you can add or remove the scrolling ability as needed with CSS or manipulate with Javascript if needed.

Comment: Thnxs , is it possible to display the fetched data using this -- $('elementid').html(bla bla);

Comment: Definitely.  Best way to do it IMHO.  Plus you could add a little flair in there with some resizing or collapsing/expanding. Just throwin that out there.  Have fun with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using text area instead of text box for longer text to display.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Your text here
</textarea>
```

you can customized the size of the text area by using the rows and cols attribute of the element.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `<textarea>`

More Information here

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

with `<textarea>` you can use this stylish plugin also

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

or if you have only read only data i.e. no need of edit functionality use `<div>` apply some css and you are ready to do

you can set it's `text` or `html` property like this

```
$('#YourDivId').text('Your Text here');
```

or

```
$('#YourDivId').html('Your Text here');
```

Comment: yes for sure. if your data is in html format you can use .html('Your Text here') or it is simple text you can use .text('Your Text here')